# Subscription ProductPayPAl

Tags: magento2, paypal

I am working on PayPal subscription recurring when I add 2 product in my cart 1 is simple and other is subscription and place an order using this calls

```
if ($product->getCryozonicSubEnabled())
            {
                $interval = ucfirst($product->getCryozonicSubInterval());
                $intervalCount = $product->getCryozonicSubIntervalCount();

                $api->callCreateRecurringPaymentsProfile($interval,$product->getName(),$intervalCount);
            }
             if (!$product->getCryozonicSubEnabled())
            {
                $api->callDoExpressCheckoutPayment($data);
            }
```

the problem is that in paypal both product in payment and recuring also creating.